# Python append matrix along given dimension

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

In a loop with over 200 iterations, I have a temporary output `temp.shape = (1L, 2L, 128L, 30L, 3L)`.

I would like to append several of these `temp` matrices together along the 5th dimension (`3L`),

such that the total output would be `Total.shape = (1L, 2L, 128L, 30L, 600L)`

I believe I need to use `np.stack`, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

For example, I try:

`Total = np.stack((Total, temp), axis=5)`,

but this fails after a few iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.stack` is not appropriate here because it appends arrays along a *new* axis. What you are looking for is `np.concatenate`. You could call it like

```
total = np.concatenate((total, temp), axis=4)
```

However, this will actually be quite inefficient because every call to `concatenate` creates a new array, copying all the content. So you would copy stuff around 200 times. A better way would be to collect all the `temp` arrays in a list first:

```
list_of_temps = ...  # this contains the 200 (1, 2, 128, 30, 3) arrays
total = np.concatenate(list_of_temps, axis=4)
```

This way you avoid inefficient repeated copying of array contents. Probably an even better choice would be to have a generator over the `temp` arrays instead of a list to avoid even creating the `list_of_temps`.

EDIT: This is how it would look like in context: Say right now you are doing

```
total = np.empty((1, 2, 128, 30, 0))  # empty array to concatenate to
for ind in range(200):
    temp = however_you_get_the_temps()
    total = np.concatenate((total, temp), axis=4)
```

This should be faster:

```
list_of_temps = []
for ind in range(200):
    temp = however_you_get_the_temps()
    list_of_temps.append(temp)
total = np.concatenate(list_of_temps, axis=4)
```

I feel like there should also be a way to do this using generators (which would avoid even having to construct the list) but I have to admit I can't get that to run right now.

Comment: I'll give this a go, and thanks for the prompt reply. Please excuse my Python ignorance, but can you enlighten as to how I would gather the list of temps? If it's not too much trouble!

Comment: I added an example in context. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, much appreciated!